# Block-diagram phase noise algorithm

Tags: tikz-pgf, block

I am trying to recreate the block diagram shown on the following link
https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/phasenoise.html#fp605734-Algorithms
[image]

I tried creating it using the examples at the official site of TikZ, but my figure got "crazier" every attempt. I am gonna be frank, can someone help me with the diagram, because I am still learning TikZ, and I don't have much time to experiment with practice problems.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}
\colorlet{myblue}{LightSteelBlue!80!SteelBlue}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\sffamily\sansmath
\psset{fillcolor=myblue, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.1, linewidth=0.5pt, linejoin=1}       
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.8,colsep=1]
     [name=xk]$x_k\;$ & \\
     [name=nk]$n_k\;$ & [name=F]\fcolorbox{Navy}{myblue}{\enspace\bfseries Filter\enspace\vphantom{)}} & [name=A]\fcolorbox{Navy}{myblue}{\bfseries Angle()} & [name=C] \pscirclebox[fillstyle=solid, linecolor=Navy]{\bfseries X} &[name=yk] $\;y_k$
   \end{psmatrix}%
 \ncangle[angleB=90]{xk}{C}
 \foreach \s/\t in {nk/F, F/A, A/C, C/yk}{\ncline{\s}{\t}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  believe that I will learn a lot more by deconstructing your code, rather trying to solve the mess I made. I appreciate your help, and time spent!

Comment: I advise you to have a look at the documentation of `pst-node`, which is well-done, and illustrated by many examples

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! I feel you would learn more if you tried some code and ask questions using it once there is an obstacle. Nonetheless, here is a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\bfseries\sffamily,
    block/.style={draw,fill=blue!20,rectangle,minimum height=3em,minimum width=6em},
    sum/.style={draw,fill=blue!20,circle},
    arj/.style={-Latex,semithick}]
    %
    \path[start chain=R going right,nodes={on chain,join=by arj}]
     node {$n_k$}
     node[block] {Filter}
     node[block] {Angle}
     node[sum] {X}
     node {$y_k$};
    \node[above=2.5em of R-1](y) {$y_k$};
    \draw[arj] (y) -| (R-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  believe that I will learn a lot more by deconstructing your code, rather trying to solve the mess I made. I appreciate your help, and time spent, and I in the future when I'll need help I'll try to share code even though it isn't correct.

Comment: @Mssey You're welcome! Notice that you can give accept only one answer. That is, you will accept the last answer you clicked the checkmark on. If that is what you meant to do, this is fine, of course.

Comment: I wanted to accept both answers because practically both solved my problem, and I learnt something. Thanks for the information, I will keep this in mind.

Comment: @Mssey That's your choice. However, please consider in the future to tag your questions `pstricks` if you want a `pstricks` answer. Then I do not have to spend my time on providing an answer. Also tag this question `pstricks` such that users find it more easily. (Just for the records: I have been using PSTricks for over a decade, and I am very glad to have transitioned to Ti*k*Z.)